# Adding option to cart increments all counters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-reactivity

When I add an option to the cart, the counters of all the options increase at the same time. I tried with Vuex, but I'm inexperienced with it, so I took a simpler approach. How can I add an option without all the counters increasing?

(I put together an example of the code, so that it's easier to explain.)

```html
<template>
    <div>
         <div v-for="optionTests in ArrayOption" :key="optionTests.id">
            <p>{{ optionTests.id}}</p>
            <p>{{ optionTests.name}}</p>
            <p>{{ optionTests.description}}</p>
            <button  @click="testCount -= 1" :disabled="testCount < 1">-</button>
            <p>{{ testCount }}</p>
            <button @click="testCount += 1" :disabled="testCount > 0">+</button>
        </div>
    </div> 
</template>
 
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
 
export default {
    data(){
        return{
            ArrayOption:[
                {
                    id:1,
                    name: 'option1'
                    description: 'je suis l option 1 ajoute moi au panier'
                },
                {
                    id:2,
                    name: 'option2'
                    description: 'je suis l option 2 ajoute moi au panier'
                },
                {
                    id:3,
                    name: 'option3'
                    description: 'je suis l option 3 ajoute moi au panier'
                },
                {
                    id:4,
                    name: 'option4'
                    description: 'je suis l option 4 ajoute moi au panier'
                }
            ],
            testCount:0,
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Finally I just found, to come to what I could find, I created a button-counter component and I created my buttons in this component. I found the explanations on the vuejs doc. I'll put the link for if someone is having a hard time. After that I don't know if everything I have done and the best way, but it works. :)

the link:
https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html

Comment: I shouted victory too quickly. I thought I was successful but no, I created a button component as described in my previous comment, however I am not getting the id of the selected object. I then tried with vueX, for me it was perfect however I come back to the first problem, that is to say that all the quantities change at the same time. I will put a post in my initial post to show what I want to do named under the name: option

Answer (score 1):

What's going on here is that, while you're rendering a unique *card* for each option in your array, your counters are all hooked up to the same variable in `data`.

This means that when you change one counter, *all* the counters will update to show the new total, because they're all really showing the *same* number under the surface, even though they appear in different places.

To solve this, you'll need to store the option counts separately, so they can be read and iterated separately.

---

Here's one way you could go about doing this.

Instead of displaying and manipulating `testCount` directly, you could store each option counter as a key in a counter *object*, so that each can be incremented or decremented on their own:

```js
testCounter: { 
  "option1": 0, 
  "option2": 0,
  "option3": 0,
  "option4": 0 
}
```

Here's an interactive example showing this off!

Note that I had to use a special Vue instance method, `vm.$set()`, to make the individual counters reactive. [Vue can't track when you dynamically create new properties in an object](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects), so we have to tell Vue explicitly to add a new key for us, using `vm.$set([object], [key name], [initial value])`.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      arrayOption: [{
          id: 1,
          name: 'option1',
          description: 'je suis l option 1 ajoute moi au panier'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'option2',
          description: 'je suis l option 2 ajoute moi au panier'
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: 'option3',
          description: 'je suis l option 3 ajoute moi au panier'
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: 'option4',
          description: 'je suis l option 4 ajoute moi au panier'
        }
      ],
      testCount: {},
    }
  },
  created() {
    // Important setup step–
    //  this.$set makes the counter properties reactive
    //  so that the DOM updates when you click a counter
    this.arrayOption.forEach(op => this.$set(this.testCount, op.name, 0));
  },
});
```

```css
.card {
  background: #bbc0c4;
  border: solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-around;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p>Values: {{ testCount }}</p>
    <div v-for="optionTest in arrayOption" :key="optionTest.id" class="card">
      <p>{{ optionTest.id }}</p>
      <p>{{ optionTest.name }}</p>
      <p>{{ optionTest.description }}</p>
      <button @click="testCount[optionTest.name] -= 1" :disabled="testCount[optionTest.name] < 1">-</button>
      <p>{{ testCount[optionTest.name] }}</p>
      <button @click="testCount[optionTest.name] += 1" :disabled="testCount[optionTest.name] > 0">+</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @zcoop98 for all these explanations and details, I will be able to read the link you gave me to learn better.